# usar variavel em comando cmd com python

Tags: python, variáveis, cmd

Queria fazer um programa que abra e leia um arquivo de texto. Depois executar ou comando no `cmd` usando o que ele tinha lido no arquivo de texto mais ou menos assim:

```
import os  
nome = open ('nome.txt')  
nome1 =nome.readline()  
nome.close()  
comando =os.system ('netsh wlan export profile name="AQUI FICA O VALOR DA VARIAVEL NOME1" folder="G:\WLess" key=clear'
)
```

Comment: O que tentou fazer e por quê não deu certo?

Comment: eu iria escrever o nome da wifi no arquivo nome.txt .o programa iria ler esse arquivo armazenar na veriavel nome1 depois ele irar da um comando no cmd : netsh wlan export profile name="AQUI FICA O VALOR DA VARIAVEL NOME1"  ...

Comment: Mas qual a dificuldade? Em jogar o valor da variável dentro do comando?

Comment: exatamente. eu queria jogar a variável no comando os

Answer (score 2):

Sendo que a dificuldade é apenas inserir o valor da variável `nome1` no comando, a solução é utilizar o método [`format`](https://pyformat.info/) de objetos tipo `string`.

```
>>> nome1 = "nome_no_arquivo"
>>> "O valor da variável é {}".format(nome1)
O valor da variável é nome_no_arquivo
```

Para o seu caso específico:

```
comando =os.system ('netsh wlan export profile name="{}" folder="G:\WLess" key=clear'.format(nome1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim:

```
import os

with open('nome.txt', 'r') as f:
    nome = f.readlines()[0].strip()
    cmd = os.system('netsh wlan export profile name="{}" folder="G:\WLess" key=clear'.format(nome))
```